# How can I convert an error handling method into a Lambda function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-11

Is there a way this method could be modified into a lambda function?

```java
public static <T> void checkResponse(Response<T> response, String errorMessage, Map<String,String> values) throws IOException {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        String message = StringSubstitutor.replace(errorMessage, values);
        logger.error(message);
        throw new RuntimeException(message, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I was learning to implement lambdas and was trying to wrap my head around how I can convert certain commonly used methods that I have into lambda.

Comment: Note that while you _can_ do this, there's nothing here that would be a _good_ idea to convert into lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define an interface with the appropriate parameters, then you can use a lambda to implement it.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ResponseHandler<T> {
   void handleResponse(Response<T> response, String errorMessage, Map<String,String> values);
}
// ...
ResponseHandler handler = (response, errorMessage, values) -> {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        String message = StringSubstitutor.replace(errorMessage, values);
        logger.error(message);
        throw new RuntimeException(message, null);
    }
};
// Call it:
handler.handleResponse(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saw a compilation error Target method is generic. Should I handle the generic type Response<T> differently?

Comment: I updated the interface with Type Parameter but still see the same error.